# How to turn flat xml array into tree?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

can someone help with with the following?

I need to convert

```
<categories type="array">
      <category type="array">
        <category-name><![CDATA[Categories]]></category-name>
        <category-name><![CDATA[BAGS & TRIPODS]]></category-name>
        <category-name><![CDATA[Bags & Cases]]></category-name>
        <category-name><![CDATA[soft cases]]></category-name>
        <category-name><![CDATA[camera]]></category-name>
      </category>
    </categories>
```

into

```
<Category>
        <Name>BAGS &amp; TRIPODS</Name>
        <Category>
          <Name>Bags &amp; Cases</Name>
          <Category>
            <Name>soft cases</Name>
            <Category>
              <Name>camera</Name>
            </Category>
          </Category>
        </Category>
      </Category>
```

This has to be in XSLT 1.0.  Thanks!

Comment: Honestly I've looked at some of the examples with key generation but they don't make sense to me.  It seems like it's impossible without some sort of parent id/child id data.

Comment: Odd that five people have voted to close this question as not answerable, when an answer has been offered which the OP has declared helpful.  The question is a bit vague, but not unanswerable.

Answer (score 3):

You mean that you want to turn a flat sequence into a tree in which each parent has exactly one child?

In the template for the parent element, apply templates not to all children but only to the first child:

```
  <xsl:template match="category[@type='array']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>    
  </xsl:template>
```

Then in the template for each of the children, handle that child by writing out a new Category element and its Name, and then apply templates to the immediately following sibling:

```
  <xsl:template match="category-name">
    <Category>
      <Name>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Name>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
    </Category>
  </xsl:template>
```

In your example, the initial item in the array seems to be dropped; we'll need special code for that:

```
  <xsl:template match="category-name
                       [normalize-space = 'Categories']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

All together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="category[@type='array']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="category-name[normalize-space = 'Categories']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="category-name">
    <Category>
      <Name>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Name>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
    </Category>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From the input you give, this produces the following:

```
<Category>
  <Name>Categories</Name>
  <Category>
    <Name>BAGS &amp; TRIPODS</Name>
    <Category>
      <Name>Bags &amp; Cases</Name>
      <Category>
        <Name>soft cases</Name>
        <Category>
          <Name>camera</Name>
        </Category>
      </Category>
    </Category>
  </Category>
</Category>
```

Comment: We need to skip the first node that says Categories altogether.  I had to change the first template to   <xsl:template match="category[@type='array']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[2]"/>
  </xsl:template> for that to work.

Comment: No, you don't need to skip the first node altogether; you just have to avoid producing output from it; that's the point of the template which tests for normalize-space() = 'Categories'.  But starting at the second child has the same effect, in the input you give.