# XSL Create Parent Child hierarchy from denormalized data set

Tags: xml, xslt

Need your guidance in this.

I am trying to create a parent-child XML out of an XML that is denormalized:

FROM:

```
<Parent>Parent1</Parent>
<Child>Child1</Child>
<Parent>Parent2</Parent>
<Child>Child1</Child>
<Child>Child2</Child>
<Parent>Parent3</Parent>
<Child>Child1</Child>
```

TO:

```
<Parent>
<ParentValue>Parent1</ParentValue>
<Child>
    <ChildValue>Child1</ChildValue>
</Child>
</Parent>
<Parent>
<ParentValue>Parent2</ParentValue>
<Child>
    <ChildValue>Child1</ChildValue>
</Child>
<Child>
    <ChildValue>Child2</ChildValue>
</Child>
</Parent>
<Parent>
<ParentValue>Parent3</ParentValue>
<Child>
    <ChildValue>Child1</ChildValue>
</Child>
</Parent>
```

The problem is that I cant figure out the logic to say, get all Child element between each parent elements.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot for looking into this.

Comment: You might examine [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780330/how-to-turn-flat-xml-array-into-tree).

Comment: Are you using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSLT1.0 you could achieve this with the use of a key. You are effectively grouping **Child** elements by their first preceding **Parent** element, so you can define the following key:

```
<xsl:key name="child" match="Child" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Parent[1])"/>
```

Then, within a template that matches the **Parent** element, you can get all the associated **Child** elements like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', generate-id())"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT in this case.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="child" match="Child" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Parent[1])"/>

   <xsl:template match="Family">
      <Family>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Parent"/>
      </Family>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Parent">
      <Parent>
         <ParentValue>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </ParentValue>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', generate-id())"/>
      </Parent>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Child">
      <Child>
         <ChildValue>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </ChildValue>
      </Child>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to you XML the following is output:

```
<Family>
   <Parent>
      <ParentValue>Parent1</ParentValue>
      <Child>
         <ChildValue>Child1</ChildValue>
      </Child>
   </Parent>
   <Parent>
      <ParentValue>Parent2</ParentValue>
      <Child>
         <ChildValue>Child1</ChildValue>
      </Child>
      <Child>
         <ChildValue>Child2</ChildValue>
      </Child>
   </Parent>
   <Parent>
      <ParentValue>Parent3</ParentValue>
      <Child>
         <ChildValue>Child1</ChildValue>
      </Child>
   </Parent>
</Family>
```

In XSLT2.0 you can make use of **xsl:for-each-group**. In your case, you want to group elements starting with the **Parent** element.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="Parent">
```

Then to select the **Child** elements, you can use use the **current-group** function:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() &gt; 1]" />
```

Here is the full XSLT for 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Family">
     <Family>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="Parent">
         <Parent>
            <ParentValue>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </ParentValue>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() &gt; 1]" />
         </Parent>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
     </Family>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Child">
      <Child>
         <ChildValue>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </ChildValue>
      </Child>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should also output the same result:

Comment: Thank You Tim! You are a life-saver! Your XSLT 2.0 example did the trick for me.